# Do shockwaves grow stronger in a vacuum

Tags: space

Do shockwaves in the vacuum of  space grow stronger the further it travels away from the point of creation?

Comment: No. What kind of shockwaves are we even talking about? if you're talking about something like blasts as here on earth, there is no such thing in space. You might go to physics.stackexchange.com for answers on the science-side. This does not appear to be a world-building question

Comment: When a wave moves faster than the local speed of sound in a fluid it is a shock wave. Speed of sound in vacuum is zero, so no shock wave at all.

Answer (score 3):

No. Simply explained, the energy of the shockwave is used in its expansion and as the wave expands the perimeter expands, so you lose energy by expanding. The expansion makes the energy the wave still has spread out more, thus having lower energy as a whole as it gets the further it travels from the point of origin.

Answer (score -1):

> Do shockwaves in the vacuum of space grow stronger the further it travels away from the point of creation?

In its most basic form, a spherical wave, the intensity drops with 1/r² (r being the radius of there sphere around the center of its origination). This is simple due to the fact that the constant energy (the energy emitted at the center) is distributed at an everincreasing sphere as the wave travels outwards with the surface of said sphere being ~r² (just as Durakken's answer suggests).

It is conceivable that emissions that are not spherical waves drop with much less than 1/r² (think Laser beams with a non-isotropic beam characteristic) but if we take *Vacuum* for what it is - empty space with no inherent excitation - there is no way for your shock wave to pick up additional energy along the way.